# Which loadout is best at destroying tanks in tf2 MvM?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-mann-vs-machine

Which loadout can stop a tank the fastest in MvM? How economical are the loadouts in terms of credits spent? How difficult are the lodouts?

I'm answering my own question again, as I'm mindboggled by all the ignorance surrounding this topic. This should answer all questions once and for all. If I missed a specific loadout, specify it in the comments and I will test it and complete the list (unless its obviously inferior)

Answer (score 3):

This was tested experimentally on the map mvm_coaltown, on wave 3, normal difficulty. The tank has 28 000hp. All known tank-killer load outs were equipped with 3 crit canteens and tested: The job was to kill the tank as quickly as possible and note how far the tank got on the map.

The number is the class number, the letter is the loadout and the white numbers are the amount of credits the upgrade cost. The number following the "+" is the amount of credits spent on ammo upgrades.

[image]

All load outs:

- 1a Scout Shortstop
- 1b Scout Sodapopper (Without +10% firing speed exploit)
- (1c) Scout Shortstop + Critacola (Not noted on map, but tank actually
  got 1-2m farther. Less damage as time wasted drinking)
- (1d) Scout Sodapopper + Critacola (Not noted on map, but tank
  actually got 1-2m farther. Less damage as time wasted drinking)
- 2a Beggars Bazooka (1 crit canteen for full barrage + 6 shot barrage
  for max use of crit duration)
- 2b Airstrike BASE Jumper combo (With 4 heads on airstriker)
- 2c Stock
- 2d Righteous Bison only (Shooting diagonally for max dmg)
- 3a Phlog Pyro (Burning from the side)
- (3b) Phlog Pyro (Detonator Jumping at the rear end of the tank to
  abort mmmph animation) Damage was equal, the time spent jumping on
  top of the tank and not shooting offset the extra duration of mmmph.
  Not noted in map as equal to 3a.
- 3c Dragons Fury
- 4a Demoman with Scottish Resistance only
- 4b Demoman with Grenade Launcher only
- 4c Demoman with Greande Launcher and a Scottish resistance sticky trap set before the wave started.
- 6a Engineer with Wrangled Sentry Gun and additional Sentry Gun (I did
  several tries for optimal repositioning of sentry)
- 6b Engineer with 2 Sentry Guns and Widowmaker (No Wrangler)
- 6c Engineer with Widowmaker only (No Sentry Gun)
- 8a Sniper Cleaners Carbine Bushwacka combo

In some cases the tank arrived at the bomb site and detonated the bomb. The damage dealt to the tank was noted in these cases:

- Warriors Spirit: 28.6k dmg (Extrapolated)
- Backscratcher: 27.5k dmg (Extrapolated)
- Scotsmans Skullcutter: 26.4k dmg (Extrapolated)
- Brass Beast: 25k dmg (Only 13% more dmg than stock due to more
  frequent repositioning due to slower movement speed. Does 50% more
  dmg than tomislav point blank in theory, but only 31% more dmg on a
  tank in practice, so probably even less on robots)
- Standard Melee weapon (any class): 22k dmg
- Minigun: 22k dmg
- Huo Long Heater: 19.8k dmg (Extrapolated. Flames do no damage to
  tank)
- Tomislav: 19k dmg (86% dmg of stock due to less frequent need for
  ammo gathering)
- Natasha: 16.5k dmg (Extrapolated)
- Scout Melee: 19k dmg
- Spy Revolver: 14k dmg
- Spy Melee: About 4k half way through

Some things that we learned from this that were not obvious at all until now:

Engineer should not wrangle his sentry but shoot tank with widowmaker simultaneously (makes almost double damage). Dragon's fury is weak. If upgraded, grenade launcher is much stronger than stickies. Heavy should use warriors spirit and melee the tank. Scouts Sodapopper is only very slightly behind the Shortstop. Scout with damage scout loadout is only slighly behind Phlog. Crit a Cola makes scout deal less damage.

Comment: How about taking into account the increased flame damage that aiming upwards or away from the tank will do as pyro? As demonstrated in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=75bfSsQQxkc I think pyro should be doing better than this answer shows. The reason is that damage is based on the oldest flame particle in contact, and newer particles deal more damage.

Comment: @Robobenklein Oh I did aim up, just from the side. If you look at my map, you see that it took him exactly the same distance as me. He is playing on the same wave as me, so you can compare the results directly. He is using most shotguns incorrectly. They do more damage if close to the tank (point blank) and when shooting from the side. And he messed up all the other guns as well. I was much more efficient with all the other loadouts, especially beggars bazooka (which is the best).

Comment: @Robobenklein I did a new test without any crit canteens and indeed the Phlog was the best. It killed the tank a little bit after "2c" on the map. And the beggars bazooka a little before "2d". And of course maxing out Phlog is much cheaper. On a map with several tanks you would not have time to go back to spawn and buy more crits upgrades for your beggars bazooka, so yes, Phlog would be the superior weapon.

Comment: To clarify, when you say engineer with 2 sentry guns, are you using the mini-sentry?

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Yes, same as 6a. Widowmaker is great.